# Cron Job Script won't run. No Output and No Error in Error Log

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using a cron job, and I wrote a php script that should send a mail using MailChimp to users whose membership expires 7 days from expiry day. I plan on using cron job to run the task but cron job says no output and my error log doesn't capture any errors.

So far I've made sure the cron job command path is correct but running a test script and if I query the db directly I get the results of users expiring.

But I can't send mails to the users

This is my code:

```
include('admin/database.php'); //
require('Mailchimp/Mailchimp.php');
// Adjust days before expiry for reminder
$days_before_reminder = 7;

// Mailchimp Configuration

$api_key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";  //Mailchimp API key here
$list_id = "xxxxxxxx";    //Add your list ID here
$Mailchimp = new Mailchimp( $api_key );
$Mailchimp_Lists = new Mailchimp_Lists( $Mailchimp );
$EnableMailchimp = true;

// Prepare and execute SQL query with parameter binding
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `membership_expiry` <= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)";
$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("i", $days_before_reminder);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();

// Loop through members and send reminder emails
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $memberName = $row["first_name"];
    $memberEmail = $row["email"];
    $expiryDate = $row["membership_expiry"];

    // Use prepared statements and placeholders for Mailchimp details
    $data = [
        'email' => $memberEmail,
        'merge_fields' => [
            'NAME' => $memberName,
            'EXPIRY_DATE' => $expiryDate,
        ]
    ];
    try {
        $Mailchimp = new Mailchimp($api_key);
        $Mailchimp->campaign()->lists()->members($list_id)->post($data);
        echo "Reminder sent to $memberName ($memberEmail).";
    } catch (Exception $e) {
    $errorMessage = "Error sending reminder to $memberEmail: " . $e->getMessage();
    error_log($errorMessage, 3, "error.log");
    }

}

// Close the prepared statement
$stmt->close();
```

I did some more debugging and my latest error is this

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method
> Mailchimp::campaign() in xxxxx/membership_reminder.php:59 Stack trace:
> #0 {main} thrown in xxxxxx/membership_reminder.php on line 59

Comment: You'll need to add some extra logging / debugging code to work out what the code is isn't  doing. `echo` isn't very useful in a cron context, because the standard output may be something unusual (e.g. emails to the sysadmin or something - you can check the cron config to know this). Log such info to a file or something instead, for ease of use.

Comment: Check if your crontab configured correctly and is your script running on the scheduled time. you can test it by removing all the code related to send mail from the script.

Comment: @ADyson
 thanks, i did more debugging and my latest error is this Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Mailchimp::campaign() in xxxxx/membership_reminder.php:59 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in xxxxxx/membership_reminder.php on line 59

Comment: @ViswanathPolaki i've tested crontab is working my last error is in the comment

Comment: In future please always [edit] your question to provide updates and include important info such as error messages wtihin the body of your question, not hidden in between other people's comments! See also [ask]. Thanks.

Comment: looks like your require and include are not working in the code. place this code in the project and create a url and use this url in crontab by wget command.

Comment: @ADyson thanks for the guidance. i'm new on the platform so i'm not familiar with all the regulations and rule yet. i wanted to edit earlier but i didn't see an edit button

Comment: The "edit" button is right there under your question next to "delete" and so on, under the little blue "php" and "mysql" tags. As well as being a rule, it's simply better for your question if you put everything in the main area, because it's easier for the people trying to help you to find all the info they need. In fact that's _why_ the rule exists.

Comment: Don't know which version of your lib (MailChimp) you are using, but it's look like missing a "s" to the method "campain" => https://github.com/mailchimp/mailchimp-marketing-php